# How to populate the form with value from current page?

Tags: python, django

I am learning to build a Post-comment app on Django. I understand how and why the current user can be assigned as author in the Comment form. But I do not understand how the post_id can be assigned to connect the comment with a particular post.

Tried using various methods obtained from searching the web. I keep getting various errors- TypeError, KeyError, ValueError etc.

My models.py is set up like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')#, kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The views.py with the comment create view is as follows:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment']

    def form_valid(self, form,**kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['post_id']
            # IS THE ABOVE LINE CORRECT?
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The Answer button is on the home page included in every post block. The html for the same with the url for it is as below:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content%}
 {% for post in posts%}
  <article class="media content-section">
   <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}">
     <div class="media-body mb-8">
       <div class="article-metadata mb-4">
         <a class="mr-4" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
         <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y P e" }}</small>
       </div>
       <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.pid %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
       <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
       <div class="border border-top-0">
        <a class="btn float-right btn-info mb-0 mt-1" href="{% url 'comment-create' post.pid %}">Answer</a>
            $$$$$ HERE IS THE URL FOR THE ANSWER BUTTON $$$$
       </div>
     </div>
 </article>
 {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
```

I do not know how to pass the post_id or the id of the post on which the user clicks. Please help!!

Comment: try  form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs.get('post_id', None)

Comment: using url `path('comment/create/<int:post_id>', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create')`